# Chamada recursiva de função - Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursão, funções

Possuo uma lista de números inteiros maiores que zero. Preciso identificar aquele com o maior número de divisores. Para tal criei três funções: uma que ordena alista, uma que me devolve todos os divisores de todos os elementos de uma lista e outra que filtra qual o elemento que tem mais divisores. O problema é que não consigo fazer com que a função maisDivisores receba diretamente uma lista apenas com os elementos (sem os divisores), entende? Se eu chamar a função2 (listaDivisores) dentro da função 3 (maisDivisores) sempre dá pau. No entanto se eu chamar manualmente, funciona de boas. Já tentei todas as possibilidades e nada. Como faço a chamada da primeira função na segunda para que esta funcione recebendo a lista bruta?

> função1 (ordena listas)
>       def qs(lista):
>           if lista==[]:
>               return []
>           else:
>               pivor=lista[0]
>               return (qs([x for x in lista if xpivor]))
>
> função2: devolve os divisores de um número

```
def listaDivisores(lista):
    if lista == []:
        return []
    else:
        lista=qs(lista)
        resultado=[]
        resultado.append((lista[0],[y for y in range(1,((lista[0])+1)) if (int(lista[0]))%y==0]))
        return resultado+listaDivisores(lista[1:])
    return listaDivisores(lista)
```

> função3 devolve o número de uma com o maior número de divisores
>       def maisDivisores(lista):

```
    if len(lista)==[]:
        return "Nenhum número."

    else:
        **lista=listaDivisores(lista)**
```

> ao adicionar esta linha de comando o código não executa
>               if int(len(lista))==1:
>                   return lista[0]
>               elif int(len(lista[0][1]))

**LOG DO ERRO**

```
>>> maisDivisores(lista)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#499>", line 1, in <module>
    maisDivisores(lista)
  File "D:/Google Drive/CIn/Prog1/EE2.py", line 58, in maisDivisores
    return maisDivisores(lista)
  File "D:/Google Drive/CIn/Prog1/EE2.py", line 46, in maisDivisores
    lista=listaDivisores(lista)
  File "D:/Google Drive/CIn/Prog1/EE2.py", line 35, in listaDivisores
    resultado.append((lista[0],[y for y in range(1,((lista[0])+1)) if (int(lista[0]))%y==0]))
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

Comment: RESOLVIDO!! Exclui a primeira função. Fiz uma só. Daí o que fiz... da lista bruta pego o primeiro elemento de forma destrutiva. Com uma compreensão de lista, crio uma lista com os divisores dele, se a lista for diferente de vazio entro na função de novo, até pegar todos os elementos daí ela me dará uma lista com os divisores de todos os. depois é só comparar e me retornar o elemento que tiver o maior número de divisores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código tinha uma falha. Consertei (rsrsrs)

FUNÇÕES GERAIS

```
def qs(lista): # função quickSort: ordena uma lista, revomendo as duplicatas
    if lista==[]:
        return []
    else:
        pivor=lista[0]
        return (qs([x for x in lista if x<pivor])+[pivor]+qs([x for x in lista if x>pivor]))


def maior (lista): # função maior: devolve o maior elemento de uma lista de tuplas compostas por um inteiro e uma lista de inteiros
    
    if lista == []:
        return 'Lista vazia.'
    elif len(lista)==1: 
        return lista[0]
    else:
        x = int(len(lista[0][1]))
        y = int(len(lista[1][1]))
        if x > y: # se o tamanho da lista do elemento 0 for maior que o tamanho da lista do elemento 1, o elemento 1 é excluído
            lista.pop(1)
        elif x==y: # no caso das listas dos elementos possuírem o mesmo tamanho, o critério de desempate será o inteiro que precede a lista
            if lista[0]>lista[1]:
                lista.pop(1)
            else:
                lista.pop(0)          
        else:
            lista.pop(0)
        return maior(lista)


def divisores(x):

    if x <= 0:
        return False
    else:
        return [y for y in range (1, x+1) if x%y==0] # retorna uma lista com todos os divisores inteiros de x
```

Construir uma função maisDivisores( ) que recebe como parâmetro uma lista de números inteiros positivos diferentes de zero e devolve, entre esses números, aquele que tem a maior quantidade de divisores inteiros e quais são esses divisores. Em caso de empate (vários números têm a maior quantidade de divisores), o programa deve escolher o maior dos números empatados. Um número x é divisor de um número y se o resto da divisão inteira de y por x é igual a 0. Seu programa não pode ter laços (while, for), embora possa usar recursão e compreensão de listas. Aĺem disso, não deve utilizar o operador in ou funções como max, min, sum, etc. É explicitamente permitido, porém, criar tantas funções quanto sejam precisas (descobrir os divisores de um número, determinar qual número tem mais divisores, etc.) ou usar funções da questão anterior. Exemplos de uso de maisDivisores( ) são apresentados abaixo.

-->maisDivisores([24, 5, 9, 15, 42])

(24, [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24])

--> maisDivisores([ ])

“Nenhum número.”

--> maisDivisores([1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17])

(17, [1, 17])

## RESPOSTA:

```
def maisDivisores(lista):

    if lista == []:
        return 'Nenhum número.'

    else:
        
        return maior(qs([(x,divisores(x)) for x in lista])) # retorna o inteiro com mais divisores de uma lista ordenada composta
                                                            # por tuplas  de inteiros e listas de divisores baseada na lista de 
                                                            # inteiros fornecida como parâmetro na função
```

Answer (score 1):

CÓDIGO RESOLVIDO!! Exclui a primeira função. Fiz uma só. Daí o que fiz... da lista bruta pego o primeiro elemento de forma destrutiva. Com uma compreensão de lista, crio uma lista com os divisores dele, se a lista for diferente de vazio entro na função de novo, até pegar todos os elementos daí ela me dará uma lista com os divisores de todos os. depois é só comparar e me retornar o elemento que tiver o maior número de divisores

[image: com apenas a função para ordenar e a outra pra filtrar o elemento com mais divisores]

Comment: boa +1 @Márcio Arruda